# how to read file from line x to the end of a file in bash

Tags: bash

I would like know how I can read each line of a `csv` file from the second line to the end of file in a bash script.

I know how to read a file in bash:

```
while read line
 do   
   echo -e "$line\n"
done < file.csv
```

But, I want to read the file starting from the second line to the end of the file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 84):

```
tail -n +2 file.csv
```

From the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail):

```
-n, --lines=N
     output the last N lines, instead of the last 10
...

If the first character of N (the number of bytes or lines)  is  a  '+',
print  beginning with the Nth item from the start of each file, other-
wise, print the last N items in the file.
```

In English this means that:

`tail -n 100` prints the last 100 lines

`tail -n +100` prints all lines starting from line 100

Comment: Great answer for smaller files, however the 'sed' answer below worked better for a huge file.

Answer (score 21):

Simple solution with `sed`:

```
sed -n '2,$p' <thefile
```

where `2` is the number of line you wish to read from.

Comment: ... or `sed -e '1d' <thefile` where 1 is line to delete or if more: `sed -e '1,4d' <thefile` for *skipping* /deleting first 4 lines.

Comment: Given the question anyway, `tail` is better. I didn't even think of it at this moment, heh.

Comment: As bash is very quick, while rest of script is in bash anyway, I prefer *bash only* solutions. But `sed` is one of the lighter and quicker solution. Not for `tail`, but many time `sed -ne //p` could be quicker than `grep`.

Answer (score 12):

Or else  (**pure bash**)...

```
{ for ((i=1;i--;));do read;done;while read line;do echo $line;done } < file.csv
```

Better written:

```
linesToSkip=1
{
    for ((i=$linesToSkip;i--;)) ;do
        read
        done
    while read line ;do
        echo $line
        done
} < file.csv
```

This work even if linesToSkip == 0 or linesToSkip > file.csv's number of lines

**Edit**:

Changed `()` for `{}` as gniourf_gniourf enjoin me to consider: First syntax generate a *sub-shell*, whille `{}` don't.

of course, for skipping only one line (as original question's title), the loop `for (i=1;i--;));do read;done` could be simply replaced by `read`:

```
{ read;while read line;do echo $line;done } < file.csv
```

Answer (score 9):

There are many solutions to this. One of my favorite is:

```
(head -2 > /dev/null; whatever_you_want_to_do) < file.txt
```

You can also use `tail` to skip the lines you want:

```
tail -n +2 file.txt | whatever_you_want_to_do
```

Comment: `head -n2 >/dev/null` is a bad usage, cause depending on how STDIN is opened (block buffers): On my system, the command `seq 1 10 | ( head -n2 >/dev/null ; cat )` dont give any output, while `seq 1 10 >file && ( head -n2 >/dev/null ; cat ) <file` print lines 3 to 10.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what you want to do with your lines: if you want to store each selected line in an array, the best choice is definitely the builtin `mapfile`:

```
numberoflinestoskip=1
mapfile -s $numberoflinestoskip -t linesarray < file
```

will store each line of file `file`, starting from line 2, in the array `linesarray`.

`help mapfile` for more info.

If you don't want to store each line in an array, well, there are other very good answers.

As F. Hauri suggests in a comment, this is only applicable if you need to store the whole file in memory.

Otherwise, you best bet is:

```
{
    read; # Just a scratch read to get rid (pun!) of the first line
    while read line; do
        echo "$line"
    done
} < file.csv
```

Notice: there's no subshell involved/needed.

Comment: I'm not sure that using `mapfile` is a **must**! While this implie to read the whole file into memory and is not simplier even if lines have to be read as arrays: `while read -a lines;do ... ;done` will be simplier than having to split each arrays member from mapfile to new arrrays...

Answer (score 4):

This will work

```
i=1
while read line
 do   
   test $i -eq 1 && ((i=i+1)) && continue
   echo -e "$line\n"
done < file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just get a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while read line
do
    if [ $i != 0 ]; then
      echo -e $line
    fi
    i=$i+1
done < "file.csv"
```

**UPDATE** Above will check for the `$i` variable on every line of csv. So if you have got very large csv file of millions of line it will eat significant amount of CPU cycles, **no good for Mother nature**.

Following one liner can be used to delete the very first line of CSV file using `sed` and then output the remaining file to `while` loop.

```
sed 1d file.csv | while read d; do echo $d; done
```

Comment: Hem.. `i=0;i=$i+1;echo $i -> "0+1"` This work, but only for skipping exactly **1** line -> wrong.

Comment: @F.Hauri isn't that what is required here? Definitely OP is trying to read CSV file and want to skip very first header line.

Comment: If so, this will be better written as (without pre-setting any variable): `while read line;do if [ -z "$firstLine" ];then firstLine="seen";else echo "$line";fi;done`. Using of `i=0` and `$i+1` things not clear.

Comment: This adds an unneeded test for each line. It's not exactly optimal.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf. I second that. Updated answer with more optimal solution. :)

Comment: Two things to note: `i=$i+1` will not perform arithmetic, use `((i++))`; be aware of the subshell created to execute the while loop in the 2nd example -- variables created in the loop will not persist to the rest of the script.

Comment: @F.Hauri your example of without pre-setting any variable will only out put totally opposite of what OP is asking. It will only print very first line.

Comment: Did you test them? There is a `else` before `echo $line`! Test this: `unset firstLine;seq 1 10 | while read line;do if [ -z "$firstLine" ];then firstLine="seen";else echo "$line";fi;done` ! This will print lines 2 to 10!

Comment: At all, I agree with @gniourf_gniourf, this is not uptimum as after counting, a test will anyway be done for each lines. Take a look at my answer and/or gniourf_gniourf's answer.

Comment: @F.Hauri. Oops, my bad. Cheers mate.